# 'Object.assign' mutates state in deeper levels

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have a sample JSBin code at http://jsbin.com/givolafala/edit?html,js,console,output

```js
var oldObject = { name: 'John', address: { city: 'new york'}};

var newObject = Object.assign({}, oldObject);

console.log(oldObject);
console.log(newObject);

newObject.name = 'Mathew';
newObject.address.city = 'los angeles';

console.log(oldObject);
console.log(newObject);
```

In this example, I'm changing the **name** which is at the top level from `John` to `Mathew`. The `Object.assign` returns the new state with the new name `Mathew`. The `oldObject` keeps its previous value `John`.

If I change any value in any level other than the root, it does not work. In the example I change the city to `los angeles`, and you will notice that the `newObject` and the `oldObject` have the same city `los angeles`. So the `oldObject` state is mutated.

Is this a bug?

Comment: If you want a recursive Object.assign check out [deep-assign](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-assign)

Answer (score 5):

This is not a bug, this is called reference. There's a difference between how primitive values and objects (references to objectes actually) behaves.

```
var oldObject = { name: 'John', address: { city: 'new york'}};
```

`oldObject` consist of:

- `name` which is a string **value** (primitive)
- `addres` which is an object, so `oldObject` really has a **reference** to `address` object

Now:

```
var newObject = Object.assign({}, oldObject);
```

After copying `newObject` also has `name` **value** and `address` **reference**

```
newObject.name = 'Mathew';
```

Here you change a value of `newObject`'s property.

```
newObject.address.city = 'los angeles';
```

But here you change a property of an object that `newObject` **references**. But this reference is also  in `oldObject` so this will change `oldObject` too.

Basically both `newObject` and `oldObject` have a **reference to same same `address` object**.

What you expected to achieve is called *deep copy*.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the description of `Object.assign()` says everything:

> *The **Object.assign()** method only copies enumerable and own properties from a source object to a target object.*
> ***It uses [[Get]] on the source and [[Set]] on the target, so it will invoke getters and setters***.
>
> **Therefore it assigns properties versus just copying or defining new properties.** This may make it unsuitable for merging new properties into a prototype if the merge sources contain getters. For copying property definitions, including their enumerability, into prototypes [Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor) and [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) should be used instead.